# Is it possible to run a program at time of winreg OpenKey/SetValueEx?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, registry

I want to run my program at the time I add it to the windows registry. It currently runs after I login/out or restart. According to the docs that's completely expected however I was wondering if there was a technique to use with winreg or that winreg has that is similar to Mac OSX's Plist "RunAtLoad" key for plists?

Is there some way to add a new key/set its value AND tell windows registry to run it AT ONCE or is there a way to tell windows registry to run a key's value using python?

Comment: Why can't you just start the process yourself in your code?

Comment: Was wondering if there was a windows equivalent to RunAtLoad. Ended up doing what you suggested but since I don't do that with Mac, wanted to not do it with windows as well.